# Insert space before some character if space does not exist

Tags: ruby, regex

If a have a string like:

> "_test_teste2 _test3"

how can I add a space before the `_` that don't have a space before already and are not in the start of the string?

Ex:

> "_test _teste2 _test3"

I tried this:

```
todo.desc = todo.desc.gsub /_/, " _"
```

It works, but add spaces after every `_`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `todo`? What is `desc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>> "_abc_de _e _f_tes_fefe".gsub(/(\S)_/,'\1 _')
=> "_abc _de _e _f _tes _fefe"
```

Comment: fixed: `"_abc_de _e _f_tes_fefe".gsub(/(\S|$^)_/,'\1 _')
`

Comment: @caarlos0 edited so it does not add anything at the beginning. You did not say anything about this so I was not sure :)

Comment: just another question: how can I made it put a space following the previuos case, but, before every non-word character?

Comment: I don't understand `following the previous case`

Comment: Sorry, I mean turns `#tes1 #test2#test3 #test4/test5` into `#tes1 #test2 #test3 #test4 /test5`

Comment: @caarlos0 right now, I have `gsub(/\s*([\W])/,' \1')` but don't have time to find a way to remove the space at the beginning.