# Insert spaces after certain words in R with gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How do you add spaces behind certain words in R if they are not the last word?

So for the word "great" it would change:

"whatagreatday" => "whatagreat day" (space inserted)

"what a great day" => "what a great day" (no change, space there already)

"I feel great" => "I feel great" (dont insert space at end)

Thought it should be relatively straight forward using gsub, but couldnt get the similar [Insert space before some character if space does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966567/insert-space-before-some-character-if-space-does-not-exist) to work in R (despite adding extra backslashes).

Thanks

Comment: The adding a space part is reasonably straightforward.  The hard part is working out where one word ends and the next one begins. For example do you break `today` into `to day`?

Comment: If you have a very limited subset of English, you might be OK. If your text could be *any English*, or worse, *any language*, then I think you'll struggle to automate this. Does "certain words" mean that you know what you want to break after?  (It's worth clarifying in the question, since that affects the regex.)

Comment: Happy to deal with one word at a time, so just want to deal with "great" in the example above. Dont care whether these are real words. Also "to day" is not same as "today", thus occurences of "gr eat" should be ignored in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the following:

`great\\s*(?!$)`

and replace with:

`'great '`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/bK0vW0)

Comment: This works in perl mode, i.e. gsub("great\\s*(?!$)","great ","whatagreatday",perl=TRUE) Many thanks.